# looping through rows with a column title

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I want to get the total profit in column 2 on a csv file:
    `Date Profit/Losses
    Jan-10  867884
    Feb-10  984655
    Mar-10  322013
    Apr-10  -69417
    May-10  310503
    Jun-10  522857
    Jul-10  1033096
    Aug-10  604885
    Sep-10  -216386
    ...
    ...`

I tried to make an if statement that if row then PositiveCounter will store the positive values and NegativeCounter will store the negative values, then get the total.

```
file = "./pybank.csv"

with open(file,"r",newline="") as datafile:
    writer = csv.reader(datafile)
    # writer.writerow(["Columna 1", "Columna 2", "Columna 3"])
    # writer.writerow(zipped)

#variables
    numMonths = 0
    totalAmountPositive = 0
    totalAmountNegative = 0
    for row in writer:
        if row[0]:
            numMonths += 1
        if row[1]:
            if row[1] >= 0:
                totalAmountPositive = totalAmountPositive + row[1]
            else:
                totalAmountNegative = totalAmountNegative + row[1]
    totalAmount = totalAmountPositive + totalAmountNegative
    print(numMonths)
    print(totalAmount)
```

I except the total amount of column 2

Comment: `totalAmountPositive` is integer but `row[1]` is string, so you need to cast `row[1]` to integer like `int(row[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas for better manipulations

Install pandas

```
$ pip install pandas
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./pybank.csv")
profit = df['Profit/Losses'].sum()
```

Comment: You published as I was writing:)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Happens to me too! :/

Comment: Python has the best community at SO. We are racing to answer questions:)

Answer (score 0):

I would you Pandas library for such tasks. You can install with `pip install pandas`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./pybank.csv', sep='\t', dtype={'Profit\Loses': int64})

sum_profit = df['Profit\Loses'].sum()

print(sum_profit)
```

When it comes to `sep` your file looks like tab separated, but it could be space so change `\t` to `\s`. What we are doing is reading the file to data frame and set correct data type so that we can use sum. Checkout Pandas documentation for more awesome things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Using csv open files is not a good way to do it.
Use pandas library the following way:

```
import pandas as pd 
dataframe = pd.read_csv("./pybank.csv")

totalAmount = dataframe['Profit/Losses'].sum()
```